# background & php/jquery

Tags: php, jquery, css, background, nested-class

I'm using a jquery plugin to create an image slider with thumbnails underneath.
My goal is to have the main image's background be `bg.png`, with the thumbnail section background be `wood.png`.

I've changed the CSS to what I believe to be correct(see below), but the background of the thumbnail section isn't extending the full `961px`, it's restricted to the `921px` width I've established with the main image. I have a feeling this might be due to nesting within the plugin's php/jquery, I'm just not sure how to go about altering it to work. If that is the case, how do I fix it? If it's something else, how do I determine what it is/how to fix it?

[thethe-image-slider.php](http://pastebin.com/QJD49Qhn)

[timthumb.php](http://pastebin.com/b4M9VGWd)

[live site](http://urbanpalate.com/instyle-mag-ming-by-mango/)

Thanks.

CSS

```
.thethe_image_slider.white-square-1{
    background: url('../images/bg.png');
}
.white-square-1 .thethe-image-slider-thumbnails{
    background: url('../images/wood.png');
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    width: 961px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

find this line

`<div class="thethe_image_slider white-square-1" id="thethe_image_slider323" style="width:921px;"><div class="thethe_image_slider_inner" style="width:921px; height:392px;">`

and change to this

`<div class="thethe_image_slider white-square-1" id="thethe_image_slider323" style="width:961px;"><div class="thethe_image_slider_inner" style="width:921px; height:392px;margin:0 auto;">`

in your code

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is there any way to know exactly which of the plugins files that info is located? I've looked and done CMD+F in all of them and didn't find that info.

Comment: i found these line in view source of the live site you gave the link in question and with these changes in chrome it gave the look and feel you want check cmd+f in view source once

Comment: i mean it must be in your html file

Comment: I don't have HTML file, it's all .php or .js

Comment: Thank you again. In thethe-image-slider.php lines 269-271 are:

`$output .= '<div class="thethe_image_slider '.$arrOptions['_slider_style'].'" id="thethe_image_slider'.$oPost->ID.'" style="width:'.$arrOptions['_slider_width'].'px;">';

 $output .= '<div class="thethe_image_slider_inner" style="width:'.$arrOptions['_slider_width'].'px; height:'.$arrOptions['_slider_height'].'px;">';`


It seems relevant, but not exact..

Answer (score 1):

Move your `thethe-image-slider-thumbnails` div out of your `thethe_image_slider white-square-1` div but inside the `gallery` div. Works fine for me then.

Comment: In the context of my php/jquery file - http://pastebin.com/QJD49Qhn - how do I do that? (sorry, not very comfortable with either of those langs yet)

Comment: I am don't know php, but I think you would move the `$output .='</div>';` at line 357 to just after line 336.